# Remove object from container from within the object itself

Tags: c++

I have a class `Client`, which does some stuff in a thread (method `run`).

All the clients are stores in a list.

When a client have finished its work, I want it to be removed from the list in which it is stored.

There is what I came to so far:

```cpp
class Client
{
public:
    Client(std::list<Client> &clients_)
        : thread(&Client::run, this),
          clients(clients_)
    {}

    ~Client()
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    void run()
    {
        // The client does stuff here.

        clients.remove(*this);
    }

private:
    std::thread thread;
    std::list<Client> &clients;
};


int main()
{
    std::list<Client> clients;

    clients.emplace_back(clients);
}
```

In this code, the client removes itself from the list at the end of the `run` function.

This somehow work. I thought it wouldn't because `clients.remove` will call `Client::~Client`, which will wait for `run` to complete.

Is this actually safe? And if not, is there a correct way to do that, knowing that only `Client` knows when it should be removed from the list?

Comment: I suspect that `clients.emplace(clients)` is a typo in your question?

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes, I meant `emplace_back`

Answer (score 0):

This is really unsafe because you will call the Client destructor in the thread where 'run' is being executed, so this thread will attempt to join himself, and this is illegal.

The **simplest approach** is to detach the thread so it doesn't have to be joined and it should work. Also, you should use some thread-safe list then, since a few clients may attempt to remove themselves from it from parallel threads.

But it also not very cool. I would suggest reconsidering this idea with a shared list that owns the object that can remove itself from that list from the different threads.
The main problem here that you should do something with ownership of the Client objects so they will not trigger their own destructors, this is generally a bad idea.